# What is the proper Freenode IRC channel for my needs?

Tags: development, monero-community, irc

There are so many monero related IRC channels. Which one should I use for which topic?

Answer (score 10):

In general, you can always start out on #monero, and people will point you in the right direction if another channel seems more useful. However, if you don't feel like checking in the #monero channel first, please use this guide:

For questions and discussions related to the:

use of the monero software as it exists in the release binaries and general discussions about monero, use `#monero`

mining of monero, use `#monero-pools`

trade of monero for other currencies, use `#monero-markets`

discussion of monero activism, use `#monero-community`

use of the mymonero.com web wallet, use `#mymonero`

active writing, modification, debugging of existing code in the github repository, use `#monero-dev`

active research of features that may end up being used in Monero, use `#monero-research-lab`

general chat with other monerians about things that aren't monero, `#monero-offtopic`