# Where is a good gauge of the development activity and discussions for Monero?

Tags: monero-community

I'd like to gauge the amount of activity in the code and community involvement in Monero. What are some of the best resources to do this besides here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it on the [official Monero project site](https://getmonero.org/community/hangouts/)

For keeping up to date with development see [Following coding progress between dev meetings](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/following-coding-progress-between-dev-meetings)

For keeping up to date with broad community, Reddit pages and IRC channels are the main outlets.

### Reddit

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/ - main, general, Monero "frontpage"
- https://www.reddit.com/r/xmrtrader - price/trading discussion here
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Moonero - memes
- https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining - mining (check out the wiki, it's awesome)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMarket - buy & sell stuff for Monero
- https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroCommunity - education, promotion etc.
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Kovri - Kovri project

### IRC

All channels are on freenode. You can also access them via [freenode webchat](http://webchat.freenode.net/) if you don't have an IRC client. See also [What is the proper Freenode IRC channel for my needs?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5895/what-is-the-proper-freenode-irc-channel-for-my-needs)

- #monero - This channel is used to discuss all things Monero related.
- #monero-community - This channel is for the Monero community to congretate and discuss ideas
- #monero-dev - The many contributors and developers come here to discuss dev-y things.
- #monero-markets - We use this channel to talk about the price of Monero and other coins.
- #monero-offtopic - Chatting with other Monero users about things not related to Monero.
- #monero-otc - Over the counter Monero. Come here to purchase XMR from your fellow Moneron.
- #monero-pools - This is the place for mining questions and discussion.
- #monero-research-lab - Research into financial privacy with cryptocurrency.
- #monero-translations - Localizing Monero into other languages

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the commits ready for pulling at https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pulls

You can also idle in #monero-dev on Freenode IRC.